# Поиск блока при клике на элемент внутри другого блока

Tags: javascript, jquery

Подскажите новичку, суть в следующем:
Есть кнопки, при клике на которые они должны развертывать\сворачивать другие блоки с информацией.
Основная особенность, которую нужно соблюсти - универсальность кода, т.е не использовать для каждого события "развернуть\свернуть" отдельные ID\Классы.
Сейчас использую такую модель кода:

```
$('.click__link-1').on('click', function(){
    $('#toggle__block-1').slideToggle(300);      
    return false;
  });

  $('.click__link-2').on('click', function(){
    $('#toggle__block-2').slideToggle(300);      
    return false;
  });
```

и т.д

Пытался написать код следующий:

```
$('.click__link').on('click', function(){
  $(this).next('.toggle__block').slideToggle(300);
  return false;
});
```

Но кнопка click__link и блок toggle__block находятся внутри других обёрток-блоков, от чего, подозреваю, скрипт не может найти элемент ближайший с классом toggle__block
Подскажите решение, пожалуйста? Хотя бы в каком направлении гуглить?:)

upd

```
    <div class="service__item-container row">
      <div class="col-12 col-md-7 service__name-container">
        <a class="stretched-link service__link" href="#" target="_blank">Автосервис</a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-12 col-md-5 service__price-container">
        <a class="toggle__link toggle__link-2" href="#">Прайс</a>
          <span class="appointment__link" data-window="#service_page" href="#">Запись</span>
  </div>
  <div class="toggle__block" id="toggle__block-2"> 
//контент который надо скрыть\показать при клике 
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Приведите пример html разметки.

Comment: ` <div class="service__item-container row">
 <div class="col-12 col-md-7 service__name-container">
  <a class="stretched-link service__link" href="#" target="_blank">Автосервис</a>
 </div>
 <div class="col-12 col-md-5 service__price-container">
  <a class="toggle__link toggle__link-2" href="#">Прайс</a>
   <span class="appointment__link" data-window="#service_page" href="#">Запись</span>
 </div>
 <div class="toggle__block"  id="toggle__block-2">
 //контент который надо скрыть\показать при клике
 </div>
</div> `

Comment: в комментариях форматирование текста не получается, простите за кашу)

Comment: А не надо такое писать в комментарии. Под вопросом есть кнопка [править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1116364/edit).

Comment: @stepan-kasyanenko понял, добавил по нормальному в сам вопрос

Comment: В разметке html нету элемента с классом `.click__link`. Приведите валидный пример :)